# Facebook Oauth works but Google Oauth2 error : redirect_uri_mismatch in Django

Tags: python, django, google-oauth, facebook-oauth

I've a Django project where i want to have login feature using Google and Facebook. with the given below setup, i'm able to login using Facebook but when trying to login with Google, i keep getting : **Error: redirect_uri_mismatch**

I've tried following urls in Authorized redirect URIs

http://localhost:8000

http://localhost:8000/complete/google-oauth2/

http://localhost:8000/oauth/complete/google-oauth2/

**Settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS= [
     ...
    'social_django',  # <-- social-auth-app-django
    ....
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
 ....
 'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
....
]

TEMPLATES = [
.....
'OPTIONS':{
....
'social_django.context_processors.backends',  # <-- related to social auth
'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect', # <--  related to social auth
}
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)



LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'core:landing_page'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'core:landing_page'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'pictures')
MEDIA_URL = '/pictures/'



ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL='https'
SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE = 'social'

#facebook social auth details
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'  # App ID
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'  # App Secret


#google social auth details
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = 'XXXXXXX-XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

**in urls.py**

```
    path('oauth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),  # <-- social auth url
```

**in html**

```
    <a class="btn button_google" href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}">LOGIN</a>
```

**in google+ api**
[image]

Comment: I think `http://localhost:8000/oauth/complete/google-oauth2/` should work. Add it, wait for some time, and then try?

Comment: for some reason, it just worked right away when i tried with `http://localhost:8000/oauth/complete/google-oauth2/`

i have no idea what i was doing wrong before

Comment: 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your URL, `http://localhost:8000/oauth/complete/google-oauth2/` is correct.

Make sure there is no spelling mistake, etc.